# naive question about running time for very large counter number

Tags: counter, performancecounter, time-complexity

I have a naive question about the maximal size for a counter. For example, the following code should couldn't be done in a reasonalbe time, because it needs at least 2^512 arithmetic operations, or more essentially, it needs to change the value of i 2^512 times!

```
c = 2 to the power 512;
for (i = 1, i < c, i++) {
   j = j + 1 / ( i * i + 1 );    

}
```

But when I use a computer algebra software "Mathematica", it gives me the answer less than one second. My question is that how could it achieve this?

ps. My naive idea about the size for counter is due to my opinion about the complexity. When I read some books (not too formal, because they focus on the complexity of arithmetic operations only) about complexity, they always omit the cost of the index. I can imagine this only if the counter is small.

Comment: Sure that the loop doesn't simply go from i == 1 to i == 513? What language is that sample code? In C/C++ `2^512` certainly yields 514.

Comment: I haven't check it in C/C++. I know the input size of 2^512 is just 512. But since it appear in the counter i, it should be runs from 1 to 2^512, namely it should do the command j = j + 1 / ( i * i + 1 ) for 2^512 times, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, as your loop termination condition is fixed at 2^512, Mathematica might be able to treat this as a summed geometric sequence and so calculate it using a formula rather than having to iterate through all the loop values.

Take a look at the Wikipedia entry on [Geometric Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) and the Wolfram page on [Geometric Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html).

If this was in a normal programming language e.g. like C++, Java or C#, you'd be absolutely right! Also, 2^512 is a very large number and would overflow the "normal" datatypes in those languages.

Assuming you mean 2 to the power of 512 and not 2 xor 512 (which is 514).

Comment: Thanks. So for any program in C/C++...etc, we really have a maximal size for the counter, like no more than 2^128 or 2^256, right?

Comment: 2 ^ 512 in C++ actually means 2 XOR 512 and not 2 to the power of 512 so make sure you're clear what you mean. 2 XOR 512 is NOT a large number!!  I was assuming you meant the latter and not the former.

Comment: Also a remark, the series I gave is not geometric one. But it may have a formula for this kind series....

Comment: @Trevor Tippins: mentioned that already on the question. +1. :)

Comment: @user565739: In C/C++ you're generally limited to the sizes of the integer and long data types so uint32 or uint64 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I know 2 ^ 512 is not a large number. But what I mean is that the code I typed really do the command 2^512 times. 2^512 not large when we represent it in computer, but 2^512 times of operation is large, right? Or I misunderstanding something? For a current personal computer, how many operations it can do per second? I assumed it can do no more than 2^128  operations per second. Maybe I got something wrong...

Comment: @Trevor Tippins: sorry, maybe I confused something. I have not run it in C/C++. But the question I present is for i from 1 up to 2 to the power of 512. So I had better re-edit my question. Sorry for this confusion.

Comment: The number of ops are obviously related to the clockspeed and what the actual op is, so you might be looking at between 2^31 - 2^32 (2 to the power of 32) integer increments per second per core.  For-loops might run slightly slower than that because of the "housekeeping" required on each cycle.

Comment: Yes. So for example, each second it can increase the counter to 2^32 ( in this comment, I always mean 2 to the power...), and we omit the operations inside the "for body". Then for up to 2^512, we need 2^480 seconds, which is astronomical. This is why I think we really restrict the counter size to a proper bound and why I felt superised that mathematica had done this computation in less one second.

Comment: That's why you pay the big bucks for Mathematica!  It's probably done some sort of algorithmic optimization for you.  You might be able to get it to show you the exact code it generated for your loop.